# The loss function decreases, but accuracy on train set does not change in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss

I am trying to implement a simple gender classifier using deep convolutional neural networks using tensorflow. I have found this [model](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_workshops_2015/W08/papers/Levi_Age_and_Gender_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) and implemented it.

```
def create_model_v2(data):

    cl1_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([7,7,3,96]), 'biases':bias_variable([96])}
    cl2_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([5,5,96,256]), 'biases':bias_variable([256])}
    cl3_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([3,3,256,384]), 'biases':bias_variable([384])}
    
    fc1_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([240000, 128]), 'biases':bias_variable([128])}
    fc2_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([128,128]), 'biases':bias_variable([128])}
    fc3_desc = {'weights':weight_variable([128,2]), 'biases':bias_variable([2])}
    
    cl1 = conv2d(data,cl1_desc['weights'] + cl1_desc['biases'])
    cl1 = tf.nn.relu(cl1)
    pl1 = max_pool_nxn(cl1,3,[1,2,2,1])
    lrm1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(pl1)
    
    cl2 = conv2d(lrm1, cl2_desc['weights'] + cl2_desc['biases'])
    cl2 = tf.nn.relu(cl2)
    pl2 = max_pool_nxn(cl2,3,[1,2,2,1])
    lrm2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(pl2)
    
    cl3 = conv2d(lrm2, cl3_desc['weights'] + cl3_desc['biases'])
    cl3 = tf.nn.relu(cl3)
    pl3 = max_pool_nxn(cl3,3,[1,2,2,1])
    
    fl = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(cl3)
    
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fl, fc1_desc['weights']), fc1_desc['biases'])
    drp1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1,0.5)
    fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(drp1, fc2_desc['weights']), fc2_desc['biases'])
    drp2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2,0.5)
    fc3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(drp2, fc3_desc['weights']), fc3_desc['biases'])

    return fc3
```

What I need to note at this point is that I have also done all the pre-processing steps described in the paper, however my images are resized to 100x100x3 instead of the 277x277x3.

I have defined the the logits to be `[0,1]` for females and `[1,0]` for males

```
x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,100,100,3])
y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,2])
```

And have defined the training procedure as follows:

```
def train(x, hm_epochs, LR):
    #prediction = create_model_v2(x)
    prediction = create_model_v2(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits  = prediction, labels = y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR).minimize(cost)
    batch_size = 50
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print("hello")
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < (len(x_train)):
                start = i
                end = i + batch_size
                batch_x = x_train[start:end]
                batch_y = y_train[start:end]
                whatever, vigen = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
                epoch_loss += vigen
                i+=batch_size

            print('Epoch',  epoch ,'loss:',epoch_loss/len(x_train))
            if (epoch+1) % 2 == 0:
                j = 0
                acc = []
                while j < len(x_test):
                    acc += [accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x:x_test[j:j + 10], y:y_test[j:j+10]})]
                    j+= 10
                print ('accuracy after', epoch + 1, 'epochs on test set: ', sum(acc)/len(acc))

                j = 0
                acc = []
                while j < len(x_train):
                    acc += [accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x:x_train[j:j + 10], y:y_train[j:j+10]})]
                    j+= 10
                print ('accuracy after', epoch, ' epochs on train set:', sum(acc)/len(acc))
```

Half of the code above is just for outputting test and train accuracies every 2 epochs.

Anyhow the loss starts high at first epoch

> ('Epoch', 0, 'loss:', 148.87030902462453)
>
> ('Epoch', 1, 'loss:', 0.01549744715988636)
>
> ('accuracy after', 2, 'epochs on test set: ', 0.33052011888510396)
>
> ('accuracy after', 1, ' epochs on train set:', 0.49607501227222384)
>
> ('Epoch', 2, 'loss:', 0.015493246909976005)

What am I missing?

and continues like this keeping the accuracy at 0.5 for train set.

**EDIT:** the functions weights variable, conv2d and max_pool_nn are

```
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def avg_pool_nxn(x, n, strides):
    return tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize=[1,n,n,1], strides = strides,padding = 'SAME')

def max_pool_nxn(x, n, strides):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,n,n,1], strides = strides, padding = 'SAME')

def conv2d(x, W,stride = [1,1,1,1]):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides = stride, padding = 'SAME')
```

**EDIT 2 - Problem solved**

The Problem was fascinatingly related to parameter initialization. Changing the weight initialization from Normal Distribution to Xavier initialization worked wonders and accuracy ended up at about 86%. If anyone is interested here is the original paper http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf, if anyone knows and cares to explain exactly why Xavier works well with convnets and images feel free to post an answer.

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem, but two remarks about your code: In your conv layers, you add the bias to the weights and use the result as the weights for the conv layer. Try tf.nn.bias_add(conv2d(data,cl1_desc['weights']), cl1_desc['biases']) instead. Additionally, you do not want to use dropout layers for actual predictions/test data. Set keep_prob to 1 for predictions and test data.

Comment: Yep, not solving the problem. But I am curious is there a difference between doing the convolution and then adding biases with a simple + sign and using the `tf.nn.bias_add` function.

Comment: bias_add restricts the bias value to 1-D and requires both the bias value and the value it is added to to have the same type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bias_add for more information

Comment: The Problem was fascinatingly related to parameter initialization. Changing the weight initialization from Normal Distribution to Xavier initialization worked wonders and accuracy ended up at about 86%. If anyone is interested here is the original paper http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf, if anyone knows and cares to explain exactly why Xavier works well with convnets and images feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Have you tried batch normalization?

Comment: Yep nothing changed

Answer (score 3):

Proper initialisation of weights is often crucial to getting deeper neural nets to train.

Xavier initialisation is derived with the goal of ensuring that the variance of the output at each neuron is expected to be 1.0 (see [here](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization)). This generally relies on the additional assumption that your inputs are standardised to have mean 0 and variance of 1, so it is important to also ensure this.

For ReLU units, I believe [He initialisation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852) is actually considered best practice. This requires initialising from a zero-mean Gaussian distribution with standard deviation:

[image: heinitformula]

Where *n* is the number of input units. See the [Lasagne docs](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/init.html#lasagne.init.He) for best practices for some other activation functions.

On a side note, batch normalisation can often reduce the dependence of model performance on weights initialisation.